# Calibration of magnetometer attached to a vehicle as Figure 8 calibration isn't possible in such scrnaroo

Tags: gps, accelerometer, magnetometer, tracker, imu

I was trying to find a way to calibrate a magnetometer attached to a vehicle as Figure 8 method of calibration is not really posible on vehicle.
Also removing magnetomer calibrating and fixing won't give exact results as fixing it back to vehicle introduces more hard iron distortion as it was calibrated without the vehicle environment.
My device also has a accelerometer and gps. Can I use accelerometer or gps data (this are calibrated) to automatically calibrate the magnetometer

Comment: Rotating in clockwise and counterclockwise direction in some steep places will give you a piece of ellipsoid that can be used in calibration.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are not happy with the results of off-vehicle calibration, I doubt that accelerometer and GPS data will help you a lot unless measured many times to average the noise (although technically it really depends on the precision of the sensors, so if you have 0.001% accelerometer you might get a very good data out of it and compensate inaccuracy of the GPS data).

From the question, I assume you want just a 2D data and you'll be using the Earth's magnetic field as a source (as otherwise, GPS wouldn't help). You might be better off renting a vehicle rotation stand for a day - it will have a steady well known angular velocity and you can record the magnetometer data for a long period of time (say for an hour, over 500 rotations or so) and then process it by averaging out any noise. Your vehicle will produce a different magnetic field while the engine is off, idle and running, so you might want to do three different experiments (or more, to deduce the engine RPM effect to the magnetic field it produces). Also, if the magnetometer is located close to the passengers, you will have additional influences from them and their devices. If rotation stand is not available (or not affordable), you can make a calibration experiment with the GPS (to use the accelerometers or not, will depend on their precision) as following:

- find a large flat empty paved surface with no underground magnetic sources (walk around with your magnetometer to check) then put the
- vehicle into a turn on this surface and fix the steering wheel use the cruise control to fix the speed
- wait for couple of circles to ensure they are equal make a recording of 100 circles (or 500 to get better precision)
- and then average the GPS noise out

You can do this on a different speed to get the engine magnetic field influence from it's RPM

I had performed a similar procedure to calibrate the optical sensor on the steering wheel to build the model of vehicle angular rotation from the steering wheel angle and current speed and that does not produce very accurate results due to the tire slipping differently on a different surface, but it should work okay for your problem.